# QTreeWidgterItem - hidden value or addition attribute

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently using a `QTreeWidget` to display items in a tree. Usually it's defined based 3 column.

What I need to know is if there is a way to add a kind of hidden value or additional attribute.

Currently the tree is used to display files and browsers as a file browser. I'm displaying filename, size and date.

For each item, I would like to defined an id which refer to a specific way to access to it.

For example : file `toto.jpg` is defined by its filename `toto.jpg`, date and size but I want to also saved its id. let's say `48`.

Now when accessing to the tree, I would be able to do `item->text == toto.jpg` then get id which is a parameter of item.

here is the function I used.

```
QTreeWidgetItem* child = new QTreeWidgetItem();
child->setText(0, "New Folder");
child->setText(1, "--");
child->setText(2, "--");
child->setFlags(child->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt::ItemIsEditable);

child->setIcon(0,QIcon(":/Images/folder_pic.png"));
```

I would be interested to have `child->setIndex / getIndex` or defined a 4th column which is hidden. In that case, I can use

```
child->setText(3,id)
```

and hide the column 3

Any idea or any method (let me know if I need to switch to `treeview` instead of `treewidget`)?

Comment: Why not use your own tree item, derived from `QTreeWidgetItem`? So in your class you can define `setIndex()` to store `id` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you don't need to define 4th column or something like that. What I suggest is using `QTreeWidgetItem::setData()` function that will let you store anything (QVariant) in your tree widget item. For example:

```
QTreeWidgetItem* child = new QTreeWidgetItem();
child->setText(0, "New Folder");
[..]
int id = 1234;
double size = 12.34
child->setData(0, Qt::UserRole, id);
child->setData(0, Qt::UserRole + 1, size);
```

You can also extract these values from your tree item:

```
int id = child->data(0, Qt::UserRole).toInt();
double size = child->data(0, Qt::UserRole + 1).toDouble();
```